# How to obtain proprieties - values from WikiData

Tags: python, libraries, wikidata

I'm having trouble using a Python library to get information off WikiData.

I'm trying to get data based on the ID of a WikiData page such as "Q2" (Earth).

I'm thinking about using a dict to store a correspondence [name propriety] -> [list of values] but for now I'm just printing them.

I'm using [this WikiData library](https://github.com/dahlia/wikidata) and managed to get some result out of it, but there are some cases I can't figure out how to cover.

Especially I have problem getting multiple values out of a propriety and I resorted to hard-code some cases which I think it's not the best way to proceed.

The library I'm using seems more complex than the code I'm used to work with and so I might have missed a obvious solution provided by the library.

This is the code I currently have

```
import wikidata

idd = "Q2" # Earth
client = wikidata.client.Client()
entity = client.get(idd, load = True)
    for x in (list(entity)): # Iterate over properties
        prop = client.get(x.id, load = True)
        print("\nPropriety ID:\t" + str(x.id) + "\tPropriety NAME:\t" + str(prop.label))

        try:
            if type(entity[prop]) is wikidata.entity.Entity:
                print(entity[prop].label)
            else:
                print(entity[prop])
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                param = str(e).split("unsupported type: ")[1].replace("'",'"')
                d = json.loads(param)
                print(d["value"]["amount"])
            except:
                print (e)
```

I could appreciate any suggestion on how to get multiples value out of a single propriety or other way to achieve my result!

Comment: Perhaps the most obvious way is to retrieve data with SPARQL (using [tag:sparqlwrapper]) and to store data in RDF (using [tag:rdflib]).

Comment: @StanislavKralin seems a really great suggestion! I'll give it a shot :) Thank you